# How to get host for RDS instance with boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, boto3

I need to get host for RDS instance. I tried to do it like this:

```
import boto3

region = 'eu-west-1'
db_instance = 'db-instance-identifier'

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    source = boto3.client('rds', region_name=region)
    try:
        instances = source.describe_db_instances(DBInstanceIdentifier=db_instance)
        rds_host = instances[0].endpoint.address
    except Exception as e:
        raise e
```

Perhaps you can suggest what might be the problem. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is that the whole error traceback?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Based on [the boto3 docs for `describe_db_instances`](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/rds.html#RDS.Client.describe_db_instances), the response is a dictionary. To access your particular DB instance, access it as follows:

```
instances = source.describe_db_instances(DBInstanceIdentifier=db_instance)
rds_host = instances.get('DBInstances')[0].get('Endpoint').get('Address')
# or
# rds_host = instances.get('DBInstances')[0]['Endpoint']['Address']
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it helped! I edited the question and removed all unnecessary code, so that the question and answer will be more visible and useful to those who will find them in the future.

Answer (score 2):

This Will Fetch list of all RDS instances with DB identifier,DB Engine,DB size, DB type

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import boto3
client = boto3.client('rds')
response = client.describe_db_instances()
for db_instance in response['DBInstances']:
        db_instance_name = db_instance['DBInstanceIdentifier']
        db_type = db_instance['DBInstanceClass']
        db_storage = db_instance['AllocatedStorage']
        db_engine =  db_instance['Engine']
        print (db_instance_name,",",db_type,",",db_storage,",",db_engine)
```